# How to install Office 365 across all user accounts on one computer (OS X Yosemite)?

Tags: mac, macos, microsoft, office-365

I have a new Mac with OS X Yosemite, which came with a 1 year Office 365 personal subscription. This is the family computer and I have set up 3 user accounts. I installed Office 365 through my account, as the Admin, but the applications do not appear in my partner's or son's user accounts on the same computer. Is there some way to get them to appear in all 3?

Comment: I think The personal subscription is for one user - for multiple users you need the Home subscription

Answer (score 1):

The Personal subscription is for one user only, and the Home subscription is for up to five users. The details are at this Microsoft link [Comparing Microsoft Office Products](https://products.office.com/en-us/compare-microsoft-office-products).

[image]

Comment: This does not make sense. I recently installed an enterprise version of of Office365 where we have hundreds of licenses. Still, the apps were only available on the user account in which I installed the apps.